# How to access TextView in Activity from Fragment inside it?

Tags: android, android-activity, android-fragments, textview

I have `ActivityA` which contains `FragmentA` inside it. How to access the `TextView` in the activity from the `Fragment`.

Comment: make an interface in fragment and have the activity implement it.

Comment: Try to define ur custom method to do ur alteration for textview in fragment and call this method from activity using fragment reference whenever u wan.

Comment: Please specify what you want to achieve via accessing the activity textView within attached fragment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can either use `callbacks` or make your fragment as an `inner class`.

For `callbacks` you need to implements some `interface` in your activity let say you want to update your TextView and in the `onAttach` method of the **fragment** you can then use the reference of that interface to communicate with the activity.

**sample:**

in activity:

```
public class Question implements MyInterFace
```

in fragment:

```
@Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    youInterfaceObject = (MyInterFace)activity;
    super.onAttach(activity);
}
```

For inner class it is just easy just create a global variable of the `TextView` in your activity and call it from the **inner class**.

Answer (score 1):

Override `onViewCreated()` method inside your `Fragment` class and use the `Fragment` `View` to declare the `TextView`:

```
  @Override
      public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
          super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

          ActivityA.text_view= (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.text_view); // your TextView must be declared as (public static TextView text_view) in the Activity    

          // now access the TextView as you want
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to create a getter method inside your Mainactivity that returns your textview and access it by casting your fragment's activity to your Mainactivity.

So in your Mainactivity,

```
 public AppCompatTextView getMyTextView(){

    return myTextView;

}
```

And in your Fragment

```
((MainActivity)getActivity()).getMyTextView()
```

And do whatever you please with it.

Answer (score 0):

May not work for views, but give it a try:

```
((MainActivity) getActivity()).textViewName;
```